# MS CRM Custom Workflow Activity output with generic type

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm

I would like to write a Custom Workflow Activity which will return a value from a parent object from the parent object of an entity. For example I am on Entity A here I have a lookup field to Entity B and here I have a lookup field to Entity c. On Entity c there is a given field which value I want to return.

Is it possible to make a generic output type, so that the Custom Workflow Activity can either return a lookup or any other supported datatype?

Thanks!

Comment: "There is a given field" - this field shouldn't have a datatype defined ? Or this field will have schema name of return field ?

Comment: May be expecting you are expecting something like OutArgument<T>, T = generics

Comment: Yes I am expecting something like OutArgument<T> with  T = generics so that i can change the filed which will be returned by an input argument which tells me the name of the field on entity c which should be returned.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not possible to add an `OutArgument<T>` of any type other than the supported types (as listed [on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg327984.aspx#AttributesandMicrosoftDynamicsCRMTypes)).

I see two workarounds:

1. Add an `OutArgument<string>` and store a serialized `EntityReference` object in it. Downside of this approach is that your parameter can only be consumed by another custom workflow activity.
2. Add an `OutArgument<EntityReference>` for every entity type your workflow activity needs to support. If you are lucky you only need a few.

Comment: Thanks. As I need the output to be processed by the workflow itself I will go with the workaround number two

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the type of the output argument for a custom workflow action in the following manor

```
[ReferenceTarget("Entity Logical Name")]
public OutArgument<EntityReference> ReferenceArgument { get; set; }
```

for more information on returning values from a Custom Workflow Action you should look at this article

http://anythingcrm.blogspot.co.uk/2013/07/crm-2011-workflow-activity-parameter.html

Comment: I know how to specify the type of the output. The Question is, is it possible to make it a generic type. Do you have any idea if this is possible?

Comment: Why do you need to return a generic object. What are you intending to do with the value ? And why is it not possible to know it's data type at design time ?

Comment: I want to reuse it in other situations. So that the Custom Workflow Activity has some inputs like field to entity b, field to entity c, and type of field on entiy c so that it can return different kind of values.

Comment: I think this may be what you are after:  https://msdyncrmworkflowtools.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Query%20Values%20Step&amp